# jQuery hover on not working live works

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-hover, jquery-on

I was having problems with an

```
$('.myElement').on('hover',function({...});
```

After trying `.on('hover'` , `.hover()`, which both didn't work, I tried `.live('hover',)`.
`.live('hover',)` worked.. however, I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 so why is this?
Here's the code I was working with:

jQuery

```
$('.myElement > a').live('hover',function(event) {
    //do stuff
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="myElement">
    <a href="#" />
</div>
```

Sometimes I wonder if I'm just making dumb mistakes or the languances are just crazy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on()` only works like `live()` when you pass it a delegated selector in the second parameter. In your case the primary selector would be the container element which your `.myElement` elements are being appended to and the delegate would be `.myElement`, like this:

```
$('.parentOfMyElement').on('hover', '.myElement', function() {
    // do stuff...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for all other methods (except .live() ... and this is one of the reasons it has been deprecated) .on() will only work on already existing elements. If you want to bind event handlers also to non-yet-existing elements you need to use delegation from a higher level element.

E.g. '.myElement' is a sub element of '.myContainer' then you can do

```
$('.myContainer').on('hover', '.myElement', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('body').on('hover', '.myElement', function...);
```

The body can refer to any context or container that you need to watch events for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.myElement > a').hover(function(event) {
//do stuff
  alert('hover');
});
```

An see this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wETdB/2/)

Greetings.